# Why does $y=f(c)$ imply that $h(y) = g'(f(c))$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

**Theorem 6.3**

If $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $c \in (a,b)$, and if $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $f(c)$, where $I$ is an open interval containing $f((a,b))$, then the composition $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $(g \circ\ f)'(c) = g'(f(c))f'(c)$.

*Proof*.

What needs to be shown is that 
 $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c} \frac{g((fx))-g(f(c))}{x-c}=g'(f(c))f'(c)$.

Note that

$g'((f(c)) = \displaystyle\lim_{y \to f(c)}\frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)}$.

Define a function $h:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $h(y) = \frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)}$ if $y \ne f(c)$, and $h(y) = g'(f(c))$ if $y = f(c)$. The second centered equation on the proof is saying that $h$ is continuous at $f(c)$, that is,$\displaystyle \lim_{ y \to f(c)} h(y)=h(f(c)).$

I understand why when $h(y) = \frac{g(y)-g(f(c))}{y-f(c)}$, $y \ne f(c)$, otherwise $h(y)$ would be undefined. But, why exactly does $y=f(c)$ imply that $h(y) = g'(f(c))$?

If I were to use $y=f(c)$, then it seems that we fall into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why,

$$\lim_{y \to f(c)}h(y) = \lim_{y \to c}\frac{g(y) - g(f(c))}{y- f(c)} = g'(f(c)) = h(f(c))$$

You've effectively defined h to be continuous at f(c) by defining it to be the derivative there.

Normally one proves this lemma first, your author is combining  this into the chain rule proof:

$ \\ $

Lemma:  f is differentiable at $a$ if and only if there exists an open interval I containing $a$ and a function F defined on I and continuous at $a$, such that

$$f(x) = F(x)(x-a) + f(a) \text{ for all } x \in I$$

$ \\ $

You can construct the function as $$ F(x): = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}, \quad x \neq a$$

$ \\ $
$$ F(x):= f'(a), \quad x = a$$

$ \\ $

He/She is applying that lemma to $g$ at the point $f(c)$